# Windows 8.1 How to make IPv6 take precedence?

Tags: networking, windows-8.1, ipv6

Two machines: `comp1` with Windows 8.1, `comp2` with Windows 7. The network in the building routes IPv6.

How can I make my `comp1` default to IPv6 routing the same way `comp2` does?

On `comp2` when I run `ping comp1`, I get

**comp2>ping comp1**

```
Pinging comp1 [fe80::186:2b02:4246:819e%13] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from fe80::186:2b02:4246:819e%13: time=1ms
Reply from fe80::186:2b02:4246:819e%13: time<1ms
Reply from fe80::186:2b02:4246:819e%13: time<1ms
Reply from fe80::186:2b02:4246:819e%13: time<1ms
```

**comp2>nslookup comp1**

```
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.203.13

*** UnKnown can't find comp1: Non-existent domain
```

**comp2>nslookup -q=AAAA comp1**

```
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.203.13

*** UnKnown can't find comp1: Non-existent domain
```

**comp2>nslookup -q=A comp1**

```
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.203.13

*** UnKnown can't find comp1: Non-existent domain
```

**comp2>netstat -nr**

```
===========================================================================
Interface List
 13...2c 27 d7 28 d9 57 ......Broadcom NetXtreme Gigabit Ethernet
 19...00 50 56 c0 00 01 ......VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet1
 20...00 50 56 c0 00 08 ......VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet8
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 11...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft 6to4 Adapter
 12...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft Teredo Tunneling Adapter
 17...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
 14...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
 16...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #5
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0    192.168.203.1   192.168.203.77     10
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
    192.168.150.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.150.1    276
    192.168.150.1  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.150.1    276
  192.168.150.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.150.1    276
    192.168.203.0    255.255.255.0         On-link    192.168.203.77    266
   192.168.203.77  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.203.77    266
  192.168.203.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.203.77    266
    192.168.220.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.220.1    276
    192.168.220.1  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.220.1    276
  192.168.220.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.220.1    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link    192.168.203.77    266
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.150.1    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.220.1    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.203.77    266
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.150.1    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.220.1    276
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
 13    266 fe80::/64                On-link
 19    276 fe80::/64                On-link
 20    276 fe80::/64                On-link
 20    276 fe80::e1:1e9e:e362:1c0e/128
                                    On-link
 13    266 fe80::583c:b068:5154:9115/128
                                    On-link
 19    276 fe80::9cbb:b663:ddb:3511/128
                                    On-link
  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
 13    266 ff00::/8                 On-link
 19    276 ff00::/8                 On-link
 20    276 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

On `comp1` when I run `ping comp2`, I get

**comp1>ping comp2**

```
Pinging comp2 [192.168.203.77] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
```

**comp1>netsh interface ipv6 show prefixpolicies:**

```
Precedence  Label  Prefix
----------  -----  -------------
    50      0  ::1/128
    40      1  ::/0
    35      4  ::ffff:0:0/96
    30      2  2002::/16
     5      5  2001::/32
     3     13  fc00::/7
     1     11  fec0::/10
     1     12  3ffe::/16
     1      3  ::/96
```

NS lookup and netstat:

**comp1>nslookup comp2**

```
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.203.13

Name:    comp2.domain.local
Address:  192.168.203.77
```

**comp1>nslookup -q=AAAA comp2**

```
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.203.13

Name:    comp2.domain.local
```

**comp1>nslookup -q=A comp2**

```
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.203.13

Name:    comp2.domain.local
Address:  192.168.203.77
```

**comp1>netstat -nr**

```
===========================================================================
Interface List
 22...02 08 ca 56 98 dd ......Microsoft Hosted Network Virtual Adapter
 19...00 ff d8 01 e3 7f ......TAP-Windows Adapter V9
  7...06 08 ca 56 98 dd ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
  4...c8 60 00 33 9c 21 ......Qualcomm Atheros AR8151 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller (NDIS 6.30)
  3...00 08 ca 56 98 dd ......802.11n Wireless LAN Card
 17...00 50 56 c0 00 01 ......VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet1
 18...00 50 56 c0 00 08 ......VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet8
 20...00 09 0f fe 00 01 ......Fortinet virtual adapter
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
  5...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
 23...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #6
  6...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #7
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0    192.168.203.1  192.168.203.123    200
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
    192.168.116.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.116.1    276
    192.168.116.1  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.116.1    276
  192.168.116.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.116.1    276
    192.168.153.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.153.1    276
    192.168.153.1  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.153.1    276
  192.168.153.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.153.1    276
    192.168.203.0    255.255.255.0         On-link   192.168.203.123    356
  192.168.203.123  255.255.255.255         On-link   192.168.203.123    356
  192.168.203.255  255.255.255.255         On-link   192.168.203.123    356
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.153.1    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.116.1    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link   192.168.203.123    356
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.153.1    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.116.1    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link   192.168.203.123    356
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
 17    276 fe80::/64                On-link
 18    276 fe80::/64                On-link
  4    276 fe80::/64                On-link
  4    276 fe80::186:2b02:4246:819e/128
                                    On-link
 18    276 fe80::29c3:4cc7:3fa8:b410/128
                                    On-link
 17    276 fe80::35d2:a8fb:4bd0:f692/128
                                    On-link
  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
 17    276 ff00::/8                 On-link
 18    276 ff00::/8                 On-link
  4    276 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

Also, I previously ran this thing:

http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9732130

Comment: Warning: http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9732130 is not an informational page, but a download to some unidentified *.msi file :( :( :(  I've some questions that might (or not) help.  What happens when you nslookup comp1, nslookup -q=AAAA comp1, nslookup -q=A comp1, and similar from comp2.  On comp2, netstat -nr will show you an interface identifier of 13 used for the NIC that reaches comp1.  What is the corresponding interface identifier that comp1 needs to use to reach comp2?  Can you "ping -6 comp2" (from comp1) by specifying IP?  Are both firewalls disabled?  (That alone could affect it.)

Comment: You are right, the link goes to MSI file. I looked inside and the most I could find was it making netsh prefix policies look like what I posted above. I put the info about nslookups and netstat from both machines in the original question. As for `ping -6`, I get `Ping request could not find host comp2. Please check the name and try again.` if I put a hostname there, or `PING: transmit failed. General failure.` if I put IPv6 address.

Comment: I'm not yet convinced that your comp1 doesn't default to IPv6.  (Could be true, but there are some other things to look into here...)  comp1 cannot look up comp2's AAAA record.  That will prevent comp1 from using DNS name resolution by simply looking up "comp2".  Before trying to fix DNS/hosts.txt/etc, verify that comp1 can even reach comp2 by IP.  It seems comp2's IPv6 link-local is fe80::583c:b068:5154:9115 so try having comp1 run: ping -6 fe80::583c:b068:5154:9115%4 (if you're trying to use the physical Ethernet).  See if comp2 can ping -6 fe80::583c:b068:5154:9115%13